# How to get console.log() outputs from a BlackBerry device?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I want to debug an application running on the device. I found this for tablets:

http://devblog.blackberry.com/2011/06/debugging-blackberry-web-apps/

I'm looking to do the same thing for BlackBerry smartphones.
In particular:

1. How can find the IP address of my phone? I can see the device is connected to my PC in Device Manager, but how can I get the IP address?
2. How can I enable Web Inspector on my phone? I'm using a 9790 on OS7. Couldn't find the same options described in the article above on my device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**- To find your IP Address**: If your BB is only connected to 3G network, it will not have an active IP address, but if you connect via Wi-Fi, it will be assigned an IP address (except when that network does not use DHCP - not so often). Suppose that your device has an IP and you want to see it. Try opening Option menu -> Device -> Device and Status Information. Your IP should be displayed there. If it's 0.0.0.0, your device does not have an active IP.

**- To open Web Inspector**: Open your browser -> Menu -> Options -> Enable Developer Tools. Save it. Tap the Menu again -> Developer Tools –> Enable Web Inspector. A popup shows you your IP address for your Web Inspector session. Next, open Safari and type your URL including your given IP address and port number. Those tabs on your BlackBerry Browser are shown with links. Click on any of those to open Web Inspector.

Hope it helps.